# How can I prevent or convert percent escaping in a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping

```
> params
=> {:d=>"http://lvh.me/images/no_avatar.png", :s=>"67"}
```

If I do:

```
params.to_param
```

I get:

```
"d%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flvh.me%252Fimages%252Fno_avatar.png%26s%3D67=Object"
```

where as I want only:

```
http://lvh.me/images/no_avatar.png
```

My first idea was to do `params[:d]`, but that seems kinda hacky. Any recommends?

Comment: Check out the [`unicode`](https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode) gem. It's specifically for this.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i am seeing

```
require 'uri'

enc_uri = URI.escape("http://example.com/?a=\111\\115")
p enc_uri
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"

p URI.unescape(enc_uri)
# => "http://example.com/?a=\t\r"
```